# Multidimensional array to a nested multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
   sid         sname               did               dname
    1         Basketball            1                 Mini
    1         Basketball            3                 Cadet
    2         Baseball              8             Little League
    2         Baseball              6             Junior League
    1         Basketball            5                Masters
```

I was trying to get this and transform it to a nested array like so:

```
 array('Basketball' => array(
                        'id' => 1, 
                        'divisions' => array(
                                          1 => 'Mini',
                                          3 => 'Cadet',
                                          5 => 'Masters'
                                       )
                       ),
       'Baseball' => array(
                        'id' => 2, 
                        'divisions' => array(
                                          8 => 'Little League',
                                          6 => 'Junior League'
                                       )
                       )
 );
```

And I am using this foreach loop which is not working, it replaces each division entry so I'm left with only one division entry which is the last entry.

```
$result = '';
foreach($row as $r) 
{

     $result[$r['sname']] = array('id' => $r['sid'], 'divisions' => array($r['did'] => $r['dname']));

}
```

This foreach loop gives me this result:

```
 array('Basketball' => array(
                        'id' => 1, 
                        'divisions' => array(
                                          5 => 'Masters'
                                       )
                       ),
       'Baseball' => array(
                        'id' => 2, 
                        'divisions' => array(
                                          6 => 'Junior League'
                                       )
                       )
 );
```

I don't understand what is wrong here.. can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you redefine `$result[$r['sname']]` each time.  You only need to define it if it is not already defined.

```
$result = array(); // initialize this to an appropriate type!
foreach($row as $r) 
{

   if(!isset($result[$r['sname']]))
   {
      $result[$r['sname']] = array('id' => $r['sid'], 'divisions' => array($r['did'] => $r['dname']));
      continue;
   }
   $result[$r['sname']]['divisions'][$r['did']] = $r['dname'];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
foreach($row as $r) 
{

     $result[$r['sname']]['id'] = $r['sid'];
     $result[$r['sname']]['divisions'][$r['did']] = $r['dname'];

}
```

Comment: +1 Assuming it works, this is a pretty elegant read.  Of course it re-initializes the 'id' value each time, but that's not so expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Check for existence of the key with `isset()` or `array_key_exists()` beforehand so that it doesn't get rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want:

```
$result[$r['sname']][] = array('id' => $r['sid'], 'divisions' => array($r['did'] => $r['dname']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach($row as $r) 
{
    if(isset($result[$r['sname']]))
    {
        array_push($result[$r['sname']], array('id' => $r['sid'], 'divisions' => array($r['did'] => $r['dname'])));
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$r['sname']] = array('id' => $r['sid'], 'divisions' => array($r['did'] => $r['dname']))
    }
}
```

What you are currently doing is overwriting the entry for `$result[$r['sname']]`, so it will only ever have one array in it.

I use the `if` because `$array[] =` is quicker than `array_push` [see php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)